# Xpages: how to have a custom function return type ahead values

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a SSJS object/function that does a custom full text search, as the results need to be in a specific order defined by my client.  This function works fine in the search results view.  It has a method to build the search query (add the * and the AND and all that), a property that returns the sorted results and I just added a method that returns the HTML needed for the type ahead.

My object is called SortedSearchResults. It needs to be instantiated with the search query in order to get the results and the type ahead HTML.  How would I code that in the the type ahead values, so I don'T end up creating one SortedSearchResults object each time a letter is added to the type ahead field?

Would I be better off with a session managed bean?  Would that make it easier?  Would it make it faster?  The search is limited to a maxiumum of 15 results.

Sor far, I only used SSJS code, but I am not sure how what I should do to avoid a memory hole.  Here is the current code:

```
//TODO Memory management???
var results = new SortedSearchResults( getComponent("inputSearch").getValue());
return results.typeAheadValues;
```

How can I optimize this code so I don'T create unecessary "var results"?  Or is it OK that way???

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at this for instance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466546/can-typeahead-results-be-returned-from-a-java-function

Comment: Per Henrik,  I updated my question with the code I have so far.  All is working well, and my main concern for now is memory management with the current code.  If it's hard to deal with the memory issue using the current code, I'll explore the managed bean solution.  But since I already had the code to do the search and display the results, I wanted  to reuse what was already done, if possible and not too dangerous for the server  ;)