# XPages typeAhead does not work If you have so many documents

Tags: xpages, typeahead

TypeAhead works fine If you don't have so many documents. If i delete lots of them typeAhead works. I think there is a limitation @DbColumn() in typeahead option.

How to solve this problem? It's like a 64k size problem but any suggestion is important

Thanks in advance
C.A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using @DBColumn() or @DBLookup() to populate your typeahead? They do have 64K limits. (I'm not sure as I read your question, so I ask for clarification).

If so, you might want to consider looking at links like this [Can typeahead results be returned from a java function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466546/can-typeahead-results-be-returned-from-a-java-function),

I've recently done one with a massive number of documents (millions). I used this, but since it was taking a lot of time to return, I changed it to get the first selected entry in the view (based on the value from the AJAX typeahead), created a ViewNavigator from that entry, and used the setBufferMaxEntires property to restrict the size of the returned ViewNavigator. This lets the process go quite fast.

Brian

UPDATE:

As requested. I started with using results like I linked above, then I added

```
ViewEntry startEntry = canQLView.getEntryByKey(searchValue, false);
        allObjects.addElement(startEntry);

        if (startEntry != null) {
            ViewNavigator matchingEntries = canQLView.createViewNavFrom(startEntry);
            matchingEntries.setBufferMaxEntries(10);
            ViewEntry entry = matchingEntries.getFirst();
```

You can see I get a single entry rather than a ViewEntryCollection, start my ViewNavigator from that entry, and the setBufferMaxEntries property restricts how much is fetched - you can change it, but a low number is sensible since it's a typeahead.

Cheers,
Brian

Comment: I used @DbColumn because I have to take values in the first column of the view i use. I have 43.000 record for typeahead. It can take a little bit more time to return :)
is it possible to send me an example code. I am stucked :(

Comment: The view that i use for should be categorized right? 
I couldn't follow all steps you mentioned. I am new one at XPages :(
in that code you wrote above there is "searchValue" I did not get it Where does it come from? what is the exact defination of searchValue?

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help

Comment: I found this and ftSearch helped me :)
http://devxpages.blogspot.com.tr/2010/04/extending-xpages-type-ahead.html

Comment: The view does not need to be categorized, but the first column should be sorted. "SearchValue" is from the link I included, it is the value passed from the typeahead var.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there is the 64Kb limit on @DbColumn(), it's not an XPages-specific limitation and various blog posts confirm it. Ensure typeahead is only provided once the user has entered an appropriate number of characters that can restrict. After all, the typeahead should return a small number of entries for the user to select from, otherwise it's not much use. Then use @DbLookup with "[PARTIALMATCH]" or getAllEntriesbyKey. There are a number of blog posts available that give code samples.